# How to use XmlReader to read data in a List

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I'd like to take the contents of an XML file and dump it into a list.  Then I'd like to take the strings in the list and parse them for data using XmlReader.  Is there any way to do this?

I'm not very familiar with the XmlReader, and no where near an expert with C#, but I'd like to use something like this:

```
List<string>fileData = new List<string>();
string xmlData = "somestring";
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlData));

/* put all the data in a file into fileData */

foreach (string s in fileData)
{
   /* use reader.WHATEVERFUNCTION I need to parse fileData for my data */
}
```

Is there a way to do this?  It seems like I'd have to put the .Create function inside the foreach, which means that I'd have to create a new reader every time I need to use a function.  That doesn't seem like the best of ideas for many reasons.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post a sample of the xml data?

Comment: The first thing I am wondering about is how you are splitting the xml node into a list of strings... If you have a file that is an xml file I'd personally just load it up into an `XmlDocument` and then query that. You can get lists of subnodes out of it easily enough with `SelectNodes` and do any other data reading you want...

Comment: How your xml looks like?

Comment: Why use XmlReader at all? It's only required for very large datasets.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the xml you're working with:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<root><node>value1</node><node>value2</node></root>");
List<String> data = doc.Root.Elements().Select(e => e.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the System.Xml.Linq namespace, which is really simplier to use : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343181.aspx

Comment: Hmmm.  The XDocument might be the way to go.  Then I can use the XmlReader from there, I think.

Comment: Okay, that didn't work.  I thought I might try something like this:
 
    XDocument configData = XDocument.Load(@"myfile.xml");
    XmlReader templateReader = XmlReader.Create(configData);